# How to simulate bimodal disitribution with already known D90, D50 and D10?

Tags: distribution, particles

I am trying to simulate partile distribution which has double bell shape. Until now, I have found some methods such as: combining two normal distribution, Lambert Generalized Bimodal distribution

[image]

However, what I am encountering now is I have D90, D50, and D10. (D90 = a, 90% particle has radius smaller than a).

I have googled and got something related to the CDF (cummulative distribution function). However, I am stuck at how to used D90, D50 D10 I already have.

Is there any way to generate ramdom particle which has bimodal distribution with predifined condition?

I tried the particle size distribution. This is the bimodal particle size distribution. And the D90, D50, D10 is already known.